# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.utils' has no attribute 'register_keras_serializable'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection, object-detection-api

When I try to train my object detection model, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 53, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\hp\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 63, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor as ssd_efficientnet_bifpn
  File "C:\Users\hp\models\research\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 33, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
  File "C:\Users\hp\models\official\vision\image_classification\efficientnet\efficientnet_model.py", line 35, in <module>
    from official.modeling import tf_utils
  File "C:\Users\hp\models\official\modeling\tf_utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from official.modeling import activations
  File "C:\Users\hp\models\official\modeling\activations\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from official.modeling.activations.gelu import gelu
  File "C:\Users\hp\models\official\modeling\activations\gelu.py", line 26, in <module>
    @tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package='Text')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.utils' has no attribute 'register_keras_serializable'
```

What will be the reason behind this and how to solve it?

I am using Tensorflow 2.0.0.

Comment: Doing a quick search for register_keras_serializable in the repository: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?q=register_keras_serializable&unscoped_q=register_keras_serializable
it looks like that method might be in `keras.utils.generic_utils.register_keras_serializable`, in that case your import is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you are using Tensorflow model garden. I spent a good half of today trying to resolve this.

What i have realized is that we need to upgrade Tensorflow to 2.2.0 (pip install "tensorflow >2.2.0"  and furthermore in the python scripts in official/modeling/activations in gelu.py and swish.py remove the '@' symbol before tf. I tried with just removing the '@' symbol and it didnt work for me , however upgrading TF 2.0.0 to TF 2.2.0 helped.
Also like Ben mentioned the register_keras_serializable function is not available in generic_utils in TF2.0.0 folder - i tried manually adding the function block and also including a reference in **init**.py but that also didnt work.

Net summary - please upgrade to tensorflow 2.2.0 and remove the '@' symbol

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by building a virtual environment with pip virtualenv instead of conda using TF 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the tensorflow version to 2.1.0 solved the issue

```
pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
```